Setup.py install error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ethereum'
I'm trying to install a package using setup.py for a project. When I run the command python setup.py install, I receive a deprecation warning about using setup.py directly. Despite this, the installation proceeds but fails with a fatal error.
The error suggests that the file assert.h could not be found and that the Microsoft Visual Studio build tools are failing during the compilation.
setup.py file
import os
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
sources = [
    'src/python/core.c',`enter code here`
    'src/libethash/io.c',
    'src/libethash/internal.c',
    'src/libethash/sha3.c']
if os.name == 'nt':
    sources += [
        'src/libethash/util_win32.c',
        'src/libethash/io_win32.c',
        'src/libethash/mmap_win32.c',
    ]
else:
    sources += [
        'src/libethash/io_posix.c'
    ]
depends = [
    'src/libethash/ethash.h',
    'src/libethash/compiler.h',
    'src/libethash/data_sizes.h',
    'src/libethash/endian.h',
    'src/libethash/ethash.h',
    'src/libethash/io.h',
    'src/libethash/fnv.h',`enter code here`
    'src/libethash/internal.h',
    'src/libethash/sha3.h',
    'src/libethash/util.h',
]
pyethash = Extension('pyethash',
                     sources=sources,
                     depends=depends,
                     extra_compile_args=["-Isrc/", "-std=gnu99", "-Wall"])

setup(
    name='pyethash',
    author="Matthew Wampler-Doty",
    author_email="matthew.wampler.doty@gmail.com",
    license='GPL',
    version='0.1.23',
    url='https://github.com/ethereum/ethash',
    download_url='https://github.com/ethereum/ethash/tarball/v23',
    description=('Python wrappers for ethash, the ethereum proof of work'
                 'hashing function'),
    ext_modules=[pyethash],
)

Error :
(py_venv) C:\Users\Vijay.VC-VIJAYPATIL\vc_project\inhouse_projects\ethash-master>python setup.py install
C:\Users\Vijay.VC-VIJAYPATIL\anaconda3\envs\py_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
C:\Users\Vijay.VC-VIJAYPATIL\anaconda3\envs\py_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
warning: no files found matching 'src\libethash\util.c'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
internal.c
src/libethash/internal.c(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2


Please show the full error log, and if the package is public, which package it is. And if you wrote the setup.py yourself, please share it.

First bit of advice, though: don't ignore the deprecation warnings. Use pip install -e . in the package folder instead of trying to run setup.py directly.

pip install ethereum 2.3.2

Although i run pip install -e
warning: no files found matching 'src\libethash\util.c'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
internal.c
src/libethash/internal.c(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

According to their web page, the ethereum package you're trying to use is no longer supported. They say to use py-evm instead now.

Python ethereum package is no longer maintained.
No Python project should use or need it for more than half a decade now. If some project uses it, then it is up to the maintainers of this project to get rid of it.
The real problem is why do you think you need this package in the first place.
